# I need to get bit 2 in matlab

Tags: matlab

I can't get the bit 2 in MatLab
for example:

```
enter code here
% c is an array to save the get bit result
a is decimal = 253
convert it to binary
a=11111101
k=1;
c(k)=bitget(a,2);
c=0;
```

what I need is c(1)=0;

Answer (score 1):

You need [`bin2dec`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/bin2dec.html) and [`bitget`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/bitget.html).

Comment: @MaanMuafakAltohafe: Your question is completely unclear.  Please improve your question, and maybe I'll be able to give a better answer.

Comment: thank you ,
i have an array of type int64 and i set the second bit of specific location (index) in this array ,, when i tried to get back the second bit i don't have the same result of the bit 2 that i set .. thank you again

Comment: @MaanMuafakAltohafe: The following code: `a = 253; c = bitget(a,2);` results in the value of `c` being `0`.  What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: this what i need not what i get .. i need c=0

Comment: @MaanMuafakAltohafe: Then please edit your question to include your *exact* code, not pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

The code, you need to use is `bitget(a,2)` rather then `getbit`, and its little endian, so its looking from the right, meaning bit number 2 will return 0

**Updating answer to updated question:** again, you still need to be using the `bitget` command,
and it is NOT looking at the bits from the left, it is looking at them from the right.

For example if your bits were `a=11110000`:

```
bitget(a,1) = 0
bitget(a,2) = 0
bitget(a,3) = 0
bitget(a,4) = 0
bitget(a,5) = 1
bitget(a,6) = 1
bitget(a,7) = 1
bitget(a,8) = 1
```

I hope this helps

**3rd update:**

`dec2bin` will always return string values unfortunately, so I checked to see, if they output the value in vectors and for that you can use `de2bi`, so for example then 
253 will look like `x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]`, and if you want to access a particular location then you can just do `x[y]` and have your number, I hope this helps.

Comment: ok , and when is a a decimal Number not binary .. when i convert it from decimal to binary using (dec2bin) the error that show is :" can not use bitget with type char" so i used b=a(:)'-'0'; to convert char to double , i have another error that is " ???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
 I must be the same.

Error in ==> rrrrrrrrr at 204
    T_Retrive(k)=bitget(b,2); "

Comment: ahh I understand, ok give me 10 mins